# With a hidden desktop is it possible to unhide only one folder?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, desktop

Windows 7 64-bit, I hide my desktop, is it possible to only have one unhidden folder on my desktop when the rest is hidden?

Comment: Sure, Ctrl + A, Ctrl + Click the folder to unhide, now press Delete and confirm :D - sarcasm -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible as the hide desktop overwrites everything.

The only options I can quickly think that are available is to do one of the following:

1. What BloodPhilia said in his comment above (although, not the most practical solution!).
2. If you do not show hidden files, you can set everything else to hidden.
3. Install a third party management tool such as [Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) (Although I think this is just more management/organising than hiding, never used myself).
4. I think the best solution - (Being a hypocrite saying this) Organise your desktop better - create a folder and put everything you don't need in that.

Comment: Ghehe I was only joking :D And I do tend to concur with option 4 (Also being a hypocrite since my desktop is overfilled and I need the search tool to find anything on it xD)

Comment: fenses will do that, and seriously does wonders for cluttered desktops

Comment: @BloodPhilla I know, but it does work! :) @The Journeyman geek, So many people have recommended I try it... now I know that, I will try it. +1 both of you.

Comment: "Organise your desktop better" Not possible..." my desktop is overfilled and I need the search tool to find anything on it "...what about pinning a folder to the taskbar, might be my best option.